# node.js node-serialport has significant write delays

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi, node-serialport

I have a system consisting of a microprocessor connected to a raspberry pi via a serial port. the raspberry pi is running node.js with node-serialport to offer a web based user interface.

When I try to write to the serialport via the web interface, I often experience long delays before I get a reply from the microcontroller (10sec to several minutes) meaning that the serialport.write is delayed somehow. (I see no errors nor is port closing..)
This happens quite consistently after the 6th serialport write.. If I reload the browser it works fine again until the 7th request..

This is the routine for opening and pushing data to the serialport in node.js:

```
var myPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", { 
  baudrate: 38400,
  parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
});

app.post('/sendtoavr', function(req, res) {
  myPort.write(req.body.cmd);
});

myPort.on('close', function(err) {
  console.log('node-serialport closed!!!');
});

myPort.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('node-serialport error!!!');
});
```

And this jquery routine for sending a http post request to the rpi:

```
$("#btnSearchTempSensors").click(function() {
  var strCMD = String.fromCharCode(84) + String.fromCharCode(83) + String.fromCharCode(13);
  $.post('/sendtoavr', {cmd: strCMD});
});
```

When looking at the network console in chrome it looks like the http post request gets sent immediately, and when sending the command to the microcontroller via minicom over ssh there are no problems at all.

Therefore i suspect node-serialport or node.js, but how to dig further?

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.. Instead of sending the command via a http post request I used socket.io/websockets.

node.js:

```
socket.on('sendcmd', function(data) {
  myPort.write(data);
});
```

index.html:

```
$("#btnListTempSensors").click(function() {
  var strCMD = String.fromCharCode(84) + String.fromCharCode(76) + String.fromCharCode(13);
  socket.emit('sendcmd', strCMD);
});
```